# Insert Stored Procedure with WHERE clause

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle10g, where-clause, insert-into

I have a stored procedure for Oracle 10g that needs to create a new row in the table and not create duplicates.

The table allows duplicates, so long as all columns are not the same. This is because the last two columns can differ in values.

With that being said, when I try to store my procedure I get the following flags:

```
Line # = 10 Column # = 1 Error Text = PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line # = 13 Column # = 3 Error Text = PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

The procedure looks fine [given I haven't added a WHERE clause for an insert before like this].

So either my format isn't what it should be or my logic is off. 
Whatever the case may be, I have tried finding examples online and on stackoverflow and have fallen short.

Any suggestions on how I should tweak this?

```
 (val_ID              tablename.column1%type,     
  val_cat           tablename.column2%type,     
  val_sub          tablename.column3%type   

 )        

AS  
BEGIN    

INSERT INTO tablename  (column1, column2, column3)     

VALUES (val_ID, val_cat, val_sub)

WHERE ((column1 != val_ID) and (column2 != val_cat) and (column3 != val_sub));

COMMIT;               
END;
```

I have even removed the "(" in WHERE clause and nothing changed.

**UPDATE:**

tried the suggestion and all errors are gone [however the record didn't create]

```
 (val_ID              tablename.column1%type,       
 val_cat           tablename.column2%type,       
 val_sub          tablename.column3%type     

 )          

AS    
BEGIN      

INSERT INTO tablename  (column1, column2, column3)       
SELECT val_ID, val_cat, val_sub 

FROM dual 
MINUS 

SELECT val_ID, val_cat, val_sub 

FROM tablename;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mureinik 's example did negate all my errors; however, when tested it didn't create the new row.

So my current work around will be a query in VB.net checking if the value exists and then implementing a simple insert stored procedure:

```
//Make select statement and look at table for whether more than 0 rows shows up. If 0 rows, then execute stored procedure

If DsAds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then

   ...do stored procedure

End If
```

Stored Procedure

```
(val_ID          tablename.column1%type,       
val_cat          tablename.column2%type,       
val_sub          tablename.column3%type     

)          

AS    
BEGIN      

INSERT INTO tablename  (column1, column2, column3)       
VALUES( val_ID, val_cat, val_sub);

COMMIT;                 
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `insert` statement doesn't have a `where` clause. You could emulate it, though, by using an insert-select statement:

```
INSERT INTO tablename  (column1, column2, column3)     
SELECT val_ID, val_cat, val_sub
FROM   dual
MINUS
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM   tablename;
```

Comment: But this doesn't look like a stored procedure insert though. So I can use this format for a stored procedure too?

Comment: @narue1992 IMHO, the stored procedure is redundant, but sure, you can replace the current `insert` statement you have (that doesn't work, as you noted) in your procedure with this one.

Comment: And what part of this prevents a duplicate where all columns can't equal my `val` variables? Not sure what `MINUS` implies

Comment: @narue1992 `minus` is Oracle's equivalent to ANSI's `except`. If such rows exist in the table, they will not be re-inserted.

Comment: I implemented it and it still says `Line # = 10 Column # = 1 Error Text = PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored` and for some reason says my column3 name in the `Select` line is invalid [rechecked spell many times and it is correct] - See update

Comment: Ok first Select has my `val`s now. Not sure if you made an update but it works now

Comment: @narue1992 yup, had my two select lists reversed - fixed now.

Comment: the errors were gone but the row didn't create. Not sure the cause but I decided to do a workaround for now. Thank you for all the help!